Создание бота в Bitrix24
Всем привет, создаю бота в битриксе с использованием rest api, который должен ставить задачи. Логика бота такова что, пользователь выбирает категорию, по которой ему нужно поставить задачу, задаёт его, после чего задача прилетает на бота, а бот ,в свою очередь, ставит задачу на руководителя отдела. Но есть проблема. Если пользователь отправляет, конкретно, файлы, то они не приходят в задчау, в логах пишет:

{"error":"ERROR_CORE","error_description":"Недостаточно прав.\u003Cbr\u003E"}

Текстовые сообщения он отправляет как надо, а файлы, картинки и т.д. не может из-за прав, есть ли какой то способ настроить права программно или через битрикс, чтоб люди, когда ставили задачу, могли прикрепить файлы ?
Пробовали декодировать через base64, искали нужный метод rest api в документации,
На данный момент использую метод tasks.task.files.attach для добавления файлов (файлы может прикреплять только создатель бота, другие пользователи - нет)

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
